# Change build rules in Makefile to build multiple file types

Tags: c++, objective-c, makefile, clang

I want to change my Makefile to build cpp and mm files, since I have just begun adding Objective-C code into my project. This is the Makefile I have currently:

```
# Name of the project being built
PROJECT := modpe

# Name of process the tweak is loaded into
PROCESS := minecraftpe

# Local IP Address of device to SSH into
DEVICE := ryans-ipod-touch.local

# Path of the SDK on MacOS
SDKPATH := /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk

# Build using libc++ and C++11 support
override CXXFLAGS += -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 -isysroot $(SDKPATH)
override LDFLAGS += -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 -isysroot $(SDKPATH)


# Names of the tweak library, substrate filter, and debian package
TWEAK := $(PROJECT).dylib
FILTER := $(PROJECT).plist
DEB := $(PROJECT).deb
# Directory for build products like executables, object files, and dependency files
BUILD := build
# Directory for debian package filesystem layout
LAYOUT := layout
# Directory for temporary staging of the debian package structure while creating the package
STAGING := $(BUILD)/deb
SUBSTRATE := $(STAGING)/Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries
# Name of the unstripped version
UNSTRIPPED := $(BUILD)/$(TWEAK:.dylib=_unstripped.dylib)
# List of source files and their corresponding object file paths
SRCS := $(shell find . -type f -name '*.cpp')
OBJS := $(addprefix $(BUILD)/,$(SRCS:.cpp=.o))
# Supported architectures
ARCHS := arm64
ARCHFLAGS := $(addprefix -arch ,$(ARCHS))
# Frameworks for linking
FRAMEWORKS := CydiaSubstrate Forklift
override LDFLAGS += $(addprefix -framework ,$(FRAMEWORKS))

# Compiler and linker
CLANG := clang $(ARCHFLAGS)
CLANGXX := clang++ $(ARCHFLAGS)
CC := $(CLANG)
CXX := $(CLANGXX)
LD := $(CLANGXX)
STRIP := strip

# When invoked as "make VERBOSE=1", every command gets printed as it runs
ifdef VERBOSE
_v :=
else
_v := @
endif


### Build rules ###

all: $(TWEAK)

.PHONY: all

$(TWEAK): $(UNSTRIPPED)
    @echo 'Strip $@'
    $(_v)$(STRIP) -x -o $@ $<

%.dylib: $(OBJS)
    @echo 'Link $@'
    $(_v)$(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -dynamiclib -o $@ $^

%.cpp: $(BUILD)/%.d

$(BUILD)/%.o: %.cpp | $(BUILD)/.dir
    @echo 'Compile $@'
    $(_v)$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -MD -MF $(BUILD)/$*.d -c -o $@ $<

.SECONDARY: $(BUILD)/.dir

-include $(BUILD)/*.d


### Package rules ###

package: $(DEB)

.PHONY: package

$(DEB): $(TWEAK) $(FILTER)
    @echo 'Stage $@'
    $(_v)rm -rf $(STAGING)
    $(_v)mkdir -p $(STAGING)
    $(_v)cp -R $(LAYOUT)/* $(STAGING)
    $(_v)mkdir -p $(SUBSTRATE)
    $(_v)cp $^ $(SUBSTRATE)
    $(_v)chown -R root:wheel $(STAGING)
    $(_v)chmod 0755 $(SUBSTRATE)/$(TWEAK)
    $(_v)chmod 0644 $(SUBSTRATE)/$(FILTER)
    @echo 'Package $@'
    $(_v)dpkg-deb -Zgzip -b $(STAGING) $@
    $(_v)rm -rf $(STAGING)


### Install rules ###

install: $(DEB)
    @echo 'Install $(DEB)'
    scp $(DEB) root@$(DEVICE):/var/tmp/
    @echo ‘Run dpkg -i /var/tmp/$(DEB) to install.’
    ssh root@$(DEVICE)

.PHONY: install

### Offline install rules ###

offline:
    @echo 'No WiFi to SSH: Using afc instead'
    $(_v)sudo afc/afcclient put ./modpe.deb /modpe.deb

.PHONY: offline

### Clean rules ###

clean:
    @echo 'Remove $(BUILD)'
    $(_v)rm -rf $(BUILD)

.PHONY: clean


### General rules ###

%/.dir:
    @echo 'Create directory $*/'
    $(_v)mkdir -p $* && touch $@

# deploys test script
deploy: $(OFFLINE)
    scp scripts/script.js root@$(DEVICE):/var/mobile/modpe/

.PHONY: deploy
```

So far the only thing that I know to change is the SRCS line:

```
SRCS := $(shell find -E . -regex “.*\.\(cpp\|mm\)”)
```

My question is, what else can I do to make this build .mm source files *with* .cpp source files, rather than ignoring them?

Comment: Could you give an example of how you would do that on the command line, perhaps building `foo.mm` with `foo.cpp`?

Comment: what do you mean? It's a makefile. You just build it with 'make package install', and it searches for the files for you and builds/links them. But right now it only searches for cpp and I want it to search for mm as well.

Comment: I think I see the problem; you're using the language incorrectly. I think I can write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given us enough information to reproduce the problem or test solutions, so you may have to do some fine-tuning, but here's an approach that should work.

You have already modified the `SRCS := ...` line. **Once you have verified that that works,** modify the `OBJS := ...` line:

```
OBJS := $(patsubst %, $(BUILD)/%.o,$(basename $(SRCS)))
```

Then **once you have verified that that works,** add a new rule:

```
$(BUILD)/%.o: %.mm | $(BUILD)/.dir
    @echo 'Compile $@'
    $(_v)$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -MD -MF $(BUILD)/$*.d -c -o $@ $<
```